# checkbox onchange not working

Tags: javascript, html

What am I missing. None of these checkboxes, when checked or unchecked, produces any messages, even if I just past this into a clean html file. It also doesn't work even in an html file where everything else is working fine in terms of the javascript.

Here is the form declaration:

```
 <form>
 <input type="checkbox" name="all"  id="all" onChange="alert('hi')">
 <input type="checkbox" name="all"  id="all" onClick="alert('hi')">
 <input type="checkbox" name="all"  id="all" onClick="javascript: alert('hi')">
 <input type="checkbox" name="all"  id="all" onclick="alert('hi')">
</form>
```

None of these work. I also tried radiobuttons, which also don't work. What gives?

Comment: Works on my end http://jsfiddle.net/1ht55s9e/

Comment: Works for me as well on chrome stable.

Comment: Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yg7655Lb/1/

Can you see the console logs when you check/uncheck on the second row?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have JavaScript disabled in your browser, running this example on jsFiddle does output the alert messages:

[image: jsFiddle]

To enable JavaScript in Chrome

1. Click the Chrome menu in the top right hand corner of your browser.
2. Select Settings
3. Click Show advanced settings
4. Under the "Privacy" section, click the Content settings button.
5. In the "Javascript" section, select "Allow all sites to run JavaScript (recommended)"

---

To enable JavaScript in Firefox

Click the Tools drop-down menu and select Options. Check the boxes next to Block pop-up windows, Load images automatically, and Enable JavaScript. Refresh your browser by right-clicking anywhere on the page and selecting Reload, or by using the Reload button in the toolbar.

---

As the poster mentioned above, if you have any other scripts running somewhere they might be throwing up errors and has nothing to do with JavaScript being disabled.